# Cloud based file share

Tags: storage, network-attached-storage, cloud-storage

I normally wouldn't ask such a general question here. But I just started my own company and suddenly found myself in need of a team based file sharing solution. My developers and designers work all over America. We use subversion for our code, but we still have a lot of files we need to share on a network type drive with each other. If we were in the same office we use obviously use a NAS type solution.

We have a low budget and don't care as much about speed as we do accessibility. What is the best solution out there for cloud based managed storage, that you can mount like a network drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [dropbox.](https://www.dropbox.com/) Everyone has a dropbox folder on their computer, and it syncs to and from the cloud. Everyone can have their own account and share folders, or everyone can use one account. Free account is 2GB. The iPhone and Android apps are cool. If you are just sharing docs, the 2GB accounts may do it for you, otherwise it's 50GB for $10/mo.

Cheers!

Jake

EDIT: Forgot to mention, if you do the multiple account route, the referrer and the referree both get an additional 250MB free. WIN!